# Date Comparison in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) sheet (2003 and 2007) , in which I have got two columns `FromDate` and `ToDate` of the type DateTime in mm/dd/yyyy format.

There can be "n" number of records in the excel sheet.

I want to apply a validation , such that value of `ToDate` column should always be greater then equal to value of `FromDate` column, when the file is saved. If this is not the case then an error message should be prompted

Comment: You want to check all of the dates before you save?   i.e. you want keep the sheet from being saved if your test is not met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** @brettdj made a great point - it may be the case that this already exists. If so, the following will show a message with each error (which will be super annoying if there are lots) and also `debug.print` it. Note that my setup here is the same as in the screenshots below. This will need to go into `ThisWorkbook` in the VBA Editor, and the code dropped into the `BeforeSave` event (this simply shows the errors and then continues to the save prompt):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim FromDate As Range
' Note that this assumes that the ToDate column has all values
' filled out. Otherwise it will stop short.
Set FromDate = Range("B2:B" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)

' Iterate each cell, checking the value next to it and showing
' an error if the ToDate is > FromDate (ignore blank FromDates)
ErrorCount = 0
For Each Cell In FromDate
  If Cell.Value < Cell.Offset(0, -1) And Cell.Value <> "" Then
    ' Handle your error however you want - this just prints
    MsgBox "Error in row " & Cell.Row
    Debug.Print Cell.Row
    ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
  End If
Next Cell

' If we found any errors, cancel the save event
If ErrorCount > 0 Then
  Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

---

If you are entering data...

Do you require it to use VBA? I only ask because you could do this without VBA using Data Validation:

1.) Set up your data, select the `ToDate` column (don't include the column header) and click `Data->Data Validation` on the Ribbon (I'm using Excel 2007), change the `Allow` drop-down to `Date`, change the `Data` field to `greater than or equal to` and enter `=A2` for the `Start Date` field.

[image]

Now enter a few values into column `B`, including ones that aren't 'correct' (this includes any non-date [a date as defined by the cell format, in my case `mm/dd/yyyy`] as well as one that is before the `ToDate`). You will receive an error message (which you can also adjust if needed). Happy to modify the answer if you do in fact need/prefer to use VBA.

[image]

Comment: This approach assumes that the dates are typed in directly.

Comment: @brettdj Yeah, good point. If it is the case that the data is already in there, think adding a column with a simple check would be easier? All stuff I guess I should have clarified before answering (rookie mistake :) ).

Comment: @RocketDonkey/RocketDonkey :Thanks for the reply .But here , you are taking into consideration that dates are in dd/mm/yyyy format.
As I am entering data manually, how can I make sure , that it's in mm/dd/yyyy format and the validation is also applied.

Comment: @palakmehta I was actually using mm/dd/yyyy format above - I guess the numbers are a little ambiguous. As to how to validating if the format is mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy, it could get a bit tricky in cases like 08/07/2012 (is that August 7 or July 8?). You could do some logic if your "month" number was > 12, but that wouldn't be completely (I'm sure somebody smarter than I has figured this out though). If helpful, you can change the date format of the columns as well so that the dates display as you'd expect. Does that work?

Comment: @RocketDonkey/RocketDonkey :When I entered "13/12/2012" it accepted , which should not happen.The way I tried to counter it:
I selected the column,I right clicked on it and , clicked format cell.Here I selected date and the particular format.
Now , I went to Data->DataValidation and selected date in "Allow" filed and enter the range of values in "From" and "To" filed.

By doing like this it is taking date into consideration , but the validation told by you is getting lost.

Comment: @palakmehta Yeah, if you enter that string into a cell formatted like mm/dd/yyyy, it will just treat it like a string (try running the TYPE() function on that cell - it should return 2, which is a string; 1 would indicate a number/date). I see what you're saying now though - I'll update the answer to reflect a date-only approach that will handle the validation properly. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @RocketDonkey/RocketDonkey :I look forward for the answer.
Thanks !!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15638/discussion-between-rocketdonkey-and-palak-mehta)